# Need to replicate Button Dropdown with curves effect

Tags: html, css, svg, dropdown

Need to replicate this button that opens on click a div with this kinda shape (don't care about the content), I think svgs is a good way to go but can't replicate the shape. Any comment would be helpful,
[image: Dropdown button]

Answer (score 0):

You can make a svg for the 2 curves, and 2 simple rounded rectangles for the button and the menu.
for example:

```css
.svg-con{
  width: 200px;

margin-left:60px;
}

body{
background: #121212;
}


#button{
background: white;
display:block;
height:70px;
width:152px;
margin-left:84px;
border-radius:100px;
position: relative;
top:38px;
text-align:center;


}

#menu{
position: relative;
background: white;
display:block;
height:110px;
width:700px;
border-radius:30px;
top:-5px;
text-align:center;

}
```

```html
<div id="button">button</div>

<div class="svg-con">
<svg  viewBox="0 0 17 3">
  <path d="m 2 0 c 0 2 -2 3 -2 3 h 17 c 0 0 -2 -1 -2 -3" fill="white"/>
</svg>
</div>

<div id="menu">menu</div>
```